# Can't get cell from previous row in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with a bunch of custom tableViewCells. I have a button that lets the user add a new cell at the bottom of the tableview. I want this new cell to have some data displayed depending on the data displayed in the cell above it. So, in my `tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath)` delegate method, I call `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the previous row and cast the result to my custom cell. However, this causes a crash.

```
if (indexPath.row > 0) {
    let previousCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row - 1, inSection: indexPath.section)) as! myCustomCell
}
```

Interestingly, if I don't force the cast, it doesn't crash. However, this is not useful for me since I need to force the cast and access some properties that only exist in my custom class. I am sure that the cell at (indexPath.row - 1) is a cell of my custom class.

Comment: Where are you trying to do that and what is the crash exactly?

Comment: don't pull data from cell, get it from the model

Comment: Vladimir that does make sense. Stupid mistake.

Comment: However, I still am curious as to why the crash occurs.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I'm doing this inside my tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath), and the crash is the standard "found nil while unwrapping optional"

Comment: @JohnDoe: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `nil` if the  index path refers to a cell that is currently not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `UITableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath)` returns `nil` when the index path points to a cell that is currently not on the screen. See also the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:).

Instead of calling the method on the table view, you could call it on the table view's data source. `UITableViewDataSource.tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` is a function you have to implement and it should return a proper cell regardless of whether the index path is on- or off-screen.

However, an even better approach (again, as mentioned in the comments) would be to get the cell contents from your data model instead of the cell.